# Forward declaration with generics

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe6

So how to make a right forward declaration with generics?

```
type
  TGenericCollectionItem = class;

  TGenericCollection<T: TGenericCollectionItem> = class(TObjectList<T>) // line 14
  protected
    procedure Notify(const Value: T; Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
  end;

  TGenericCollectionItem = class
  public
    Owner: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>;
  end;
```

[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(14): E2086 Type 'TGenericCollectionItem' is not yet completely defined

Comment: See [How to set a forward declaration with generic types under Delphi 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6055742/576719).

Comment: FWIW, in generics, it is not usual that classes are so dependent, i.e. that the CollectionItem knows about its Collection. Generics were designed to make such dependencies unnecessary. The collection doesn't have to know about the items (except what is specified in tbe constraints) and the item has absolutely no knowledge of the Collection.

Comment: @Rudy That makes no sense. The need for items to know about their containers is totally independent of generics. Moving on from containers, not all uses of generics are containers. The inability of the language to cater for forward declarations with generics is a crushing limitation. The designers got the design wrong. It sucks.